# How do I pass a function to an angular directive inside ng-repeat (arg is undefined)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

parent directive:

```
<autosuggest
    click-match="addTag(tag)">
</autosuggest>
```

The `addTag` function is defined in the parent controller. It gets called, but the argument is undefined.

Here is the `<autosuggest>` implementation:

```
scope: {
    clickMatch: '&'
}
```

And inside the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="match in matches">
    <span ng-click="clickMatch(match)">{{match.name}}</span>
</li>
```

The `clickMatch` function is calling the parent's `addTag(tag)` function except the argument `tag` is undefined.

Comment: The "And inside the view:" HTML, is that the directive template?

Comment: Yes, that is the directive template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions passes into directives via `&` appear on the isolated scope in a modified form. They take an object of key value pairs of

```
variableNameInExternalTemplate: expressionInIsolatedScope
```

In your case, the key is `tag` and the value is `match`, so your `ng-click` attribute should look like

```
<span ng-click="clickMatch({tag: match})"></span>
```

If you also want to pass `$event` from the click, you can do the same with with the `$event` variable

```
<span ng-click="clickMatch({tag: match, $event: $event})"></span>
```

Making sure that you add `$event` to the arguments list in the template where the directive is used

```
<autosuggest click-match="addTag(tag, $event)"></autosuggest>
```

Comment: huh? you're not even calling my function.

Comment: the argument is undefined. i would have seen a different object.

Comment: One small problem, how do I pass the `$event` object?

Comment: @chovy I've edited my answer to show how you can also pass the `$event` object